# removing via from emails sent by mailgun

Tags: email, mailgun, spf

Our customers use our cloud software to send emails.  We use mailgun to send those emails.  Our customers email recipients see "via go.livehive.com".  I was told that if our customers add a TXT record, example below, the via would go away.

customer at abc.com adds the "include:go.livehive.com" into existing TXT record,

v=spf1 include:go.livehive.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com ~all

Some gmail documentation stated that we should only use one SPF record so that is why there are two includes in this TXT record. So far this has not worked, what are we doing wrong?

Comment: According to the mailgun.com documentation (https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain) you need to add the `include:mailgun.org` to your SPF record + a DKIM record that can be found in the mailgun Control Panel. This should remove the `via Mailgun.org` message. But you are mentioning a `via go.livehive.com` message, which may come from another party than MailGun.

Comment: We found the solution.  The customer adds an include record referencing a server and pointing to our server, go.livehive.com, and we have an include record for go.livehive.com pointing to mailgun.org.  The record chaining works as long as the customer provides a server name and we provide a DKIM for that server at their domain, e.g. server1.customer.com

Comment: How do you provide a DKIM for their server? Could you please explain further the solution?